# How to apply css to a native ios app?

Tags: objective-c, css, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I am working on a app were I need to apply the css style sheet to the background as a theme. Is there a possibility to apply programmatically by dragging the css file into resource folder and calling it from the documents folder.

please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Wut? `css style sheet to the background as a theme` I have no idea what you are wanting here. Btw, you cannot style your iOS app via CSS.

Comment: To repeat: you cannot style iOS native controls with CSS. iOS apps are not HTML.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it's now possible to style native controls with CSS: http://www.pixate.com/

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a custom CSS style sheet I added to my resources folder to style a `UIWebView` object. First, I put the HTML code I want to load on an `NSString` and I specify the style sheet I want to use. Then, I create the `UIWebView` object and load the HTML string with the method `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` where the base URL is the path to your app's bundle. Hope this helps.

```
NSString *bodyHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                         "<head> \n"
                         "<link href=\"default.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /> \n"
                         "</head> \n"
                         "<body>%@</body> \n"
                         "</html>", textPost.body];

UIWebView *bodyView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 400.0, 532.0, 10.0)];
bodyView.delegate = self;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[bodyView loadHTMLString:bodyHTML baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: thank u for ur code snippet i will try and get back with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/)?
It offers a `– loadHTMLString:baseURL:` method that will allow you to do what you describe.

Comment: ok thank u all for the suggestion.Its just a thought. Can we use html files to view the graphs in uiwebview, Is there any possibilities; if so please share.